# Setting binding expression in output binding of Isolated Azure Function with multiple outputs

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I've got a C# Azure Function running in Isolated process mode. It's got a `[ServiceBusTrigger]` with a POCO reprenting the JSON message received from the topic. There's a `[BlobInput]` binding, which uses a binding expression from a property in the trigger message object.

I now need this function to have two output bindings - `[BlobOutput]` and `[ServiceBusOutput]`. I have a class representing the response, with each property decorated with the aforementioned attributes.

My challenge is that I need to use a binding expression for `[BlobOutput]` that refers to a value from the input trigger - basically I want to use the same blob name on the output that I received on the input.

Below is a sample of what I have currently, starting with the function:

```
[Function("MyFunction")]
public AggregateResponse Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] BusMessage busMsg,
    [BlobInput("input/{BlobName}", Connection = "StorageConnection")] byte[] blob
)
{
    // processing happens here

    return new()
    {
        OutputBlob = outputBlob,
        QueueMessage = new($"{busMsg.BlobFileName}.json")
    };
}
```

The object representing the trigger:

```
public class BusMessage
{
    public string BlobName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string BlobFileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(BlobName);
}
```

I also have a `record` representing the queue output:

```
public record QueueMessage(string StoragePath);
```

Last is the `class` being returned by the function, representing the two output bindings. It's here that I'm running into errors with the `[BlobOutput]` binding expression:

```
public class AggregateResponse
{
    [BlobOutput("json/{BlobFileName}.json", Connection = "StorageConnection")]
    public object OutputBlob { get; set; } = null!;

    [ServiceBusOutput("queue", ServiceBusEntityType.Queue, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
    public QueueMessage QueueMessage { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Running this, I get the following error: No value for named parameter 'BlobFileName'.

How would I reference properties off my trigger, assuming this is even possible?